# Android Building a quiz app stuck

Tags: java, android

first time building a project that hasn't held my hand so i am very lost. I  built my layout here https://hastebin.com/rewuxoyina.xml and my java is here  https://hastebin.com/epiluxetal.scala I am attempting to have the score variable update when the correct radio button is selected. I have an if else setup that i got from the radio button docs but no matter what i do  i cant seem to have the variable update it keeps throwing errors . I also tried to do it in the commented out code but it didnt work either. If you could point me in the right direction that would be great (sorry still new to this)

Comment: Please share your logcat error message

Comment: logcat https://gyazo.com/1cee96e7d8182df91e89d6827692bcd2